# How is $\hat{\theta}_1=-\hat{r}\cos{\theta}-\hat{z}\sin{\theta}$?

Tags: calculus, geometry

In my professors notes he has this image (no axis labels given what so ever). Then he claims that
$$\hat{\theta}_1=-\hat{r}\cos{\theta}-\hat{z}\sin{\theta}$$
$$\hat{\theta}_2=\hat{r}\cos{\theta}-\hat{z}\sin{\theta}$$

Can someone shed some light as how the geometry in the image below leads to the conclusions above?

[image]

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: It's from an old exam question in electromagnetic field theory where I'm supposed to calculate the surface charge density of a half wave antenna positioned above an infinitely conduction plane, using image theory. But one should not need to know that in order to deal with the above, though I also understand why you would want some context.

Comment: This is a mumbo jumbo for me also. How is $\theta$ defined, how are the axes defined etc. ?

Comment: It seems as if we are dealing with overlapping spherical coordinates here $(r,\theta,\phi)$ and cylindrical $(r,\theta,z)$. So I want to express $\hat{\theta}$ (in spherical) in terms of cylindrical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinitely conducting plane is the horizontal (blue line). You want to calculate the surface density at some point $P$ on the plane. The position of the antenna is above the plane $A$, in such a way that the angle between the vertical and the antenna position as seen from $P$ is $\theta$. The vertical direction, pointing up is $\hat z$. The direction in the plane is $\hat r$. The position of the image is below the plane, $A'$. The angle between the position of the image and the vertical is also $\theta$. Then $\hat\theta_1$ is the direction perpendicular to $AP$ and $\hat\theta_2$ is the direction perpendicular to $A'P$. The angles between the horizontal and $\hat\theta_1$ or $\hat\theta_2$ are then both $\theta$, and we can write the vertical components for both of them as $-\hat z\sin\theta$. The horizontal components are $\pm\hat r\cos\theta$